# Jenkins & Maven - build process

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, artifactory

I am learning about Jenkins and I have to explore some existing build jobs that others wrote (in the company that I'm working).
So I am trying to understand a job which uses mvn command.
So under the build part (inside the job), I see these details:

**Maven version: 3.0.5
Root POM: pom:xml
Goals and options: clean install -U  -Pnotest,docs**

I'm trying to understand what this mvn command means?
I tried to google it: "clean install -U"
But I didn't find what the parameter U means.
And I don't know what is "-Pnotest,docs".

can you guide me regarding how I can find what's it? (maybe "-Pnotest,docs" is from a xml file or it's from the artifactory etc..)

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: You also need to look into the "pom.xml" file to make sense of the "notest" and "docs".

Answer (score 1):

`-U` Forces a check for miss releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories

Answer (score 1):

If Maven is regularly used in your company, and you will have to work with it on a day-to-day basis, I would advise you to find a mentor (any colleague that knows the tool well and is ready to share its knowledge with you) and work with them. Maven, when you first look at it, can be quite of a mouthful and you'll learn it more efficiently with their help.

For the problem at hand, Elarbi Mohamed Aymen's answer already tells you what the `-U` flag corresponds to. As for `-P`, it is used to activate profiles (in your case `notest` and `docs`). These profiles are usually defined in the `pom.xml` of the project being build.

See [Running Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/run.html) for the basic commands, and as advised on that page run `mvn -h` to have the complete list of flags the command can use.

Comment: Maven is software with an attitude and I disagree with many design decisions.  The advantages of dependency resolving combined with a strict "no code in the configuration file" outweighs almost everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is one of the mechanism how to handle the build process and check project dependencies, especially for Java.

One of the option can be to have physically included dependencies (artifacts / libs) in the project, but its not so useful- in case of new version, you have to replace the file, sometimes you are using same lib in more apps, ten you have to handle it manually in all projects.
Except this, there is the maven- it has a global repository with shared artifacts / libs , which are common used- ref. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

Except this, you can make your own libs/ artifacts in this case, its a modules / applications which are reusable, then you are storing it in private repository- this is the artifactory.

When you want to build your project, in case of maven project you have `pom.xml` , which is like manual for maven what to do / how to build.

`clean` and `install` are common goals, clean will wipe your local maven repository, install will download them again, with parameter `-U` it force to download them.
You can define your own goals in pom file, eg. to "tree build"- build some dependent modules, then build parent project.

Eg. with `-D` you pass parameters to the maven eg. 
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app`
- that will generate new project, based on given archetype- "template", with the given `groupID` and `artifactID`- groupID can be eg. company name, artifactID is then the name of specific app / component.

```
 -P,--activate-profiles <arg>           Comma-delimited list of profiles
                                        to activate
 -D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
```